# Knockout input type number detect up or down to add or remove item from observableArray

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js, binding

Using the following code, I want to build up a total cost of the items added using `input type="number"`.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: availableItems()">
<br />
  <input type="number" data-bind="event: {change: $parent.itemCountChange}" min="0" step="1" value="0" />
  <label data-bind="text: name"/>
</div>
<label id="totalCost" data-bind="text: totalCost" />
```

JS:

```
var refreshmentsModel = function ref() {
  var self = this;
  self.totalCost = ko.observable(0);
  self.addedItems = ko.observableArray();
  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([{name: "Tea", price: 3.00}, {name: "Coffee", price: 4.00}, {name: "Cake", price: 5.00}]);
  self.itemCountChange = function(d) {
    self.addedItems.push(d);
    alert("Added items now: " + self.addedItems().length)
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(new refreshmentsModel());
```

However I can't find out if there was an increase or a decrease, so my `addedItems` always gets a new item added, even if the count is reduced.
I have tried adding a binding to the value of the number input, but then that binds to each of the inputs in the foreach, so changing one changes them all.

Maybe it would be easier to redesign and have two buttons, one for Add and one for Remove, but if anyone has any ideas on the above that would be great!

Thanks

PS. Sorry, I tried to create a codepen with the code, but it kept giving me the error 'ko is not defined', even though I added the knockout reference in the settings window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all that needs to happen is to add an observable field onto the data in the available items, which holds the value of what is ordered. and then have a computed observable that does the calculation when something is ordered.

something like this.

```js
function ItemModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name || 'unknown');
  self.price = ko.observable(data.price || 0.00);
  self.numberOrdered = ko.observable(data.numberOrdered || 0.00);
  self.itemCost = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return parseFloat(self.numberOrdered()) * parseFloat(self.price());
  });
}

var data = [{
  name: "Tea",
  price: 3.00
}, {
  name: "Coffee",
  price: 4.00
}, {
  name: "Cake",
  price: 5.00
}];

var refreshmentsModel = function ref() {
  var self = this;

  function totalCostCalc(accumulator, currentValue) {
    return accumulator + currentValue.itemCost();
  }

  self.totalCost = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.availableItems().reduce(totalCostCalc, 0);
  });
  self.addedItems = ko.observableArray();
  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray(data.map(x => new ItemModel(x)));
};
ko.applyBindings(new refreshmentsModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <theader>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Ordered</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Item Total</td>

    </tr>
  </theader>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: availableItems()">
    <tr>
      <td><label data-bind="text: name" /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" data-bind="textInput: numberOrdered" min="0" step="1" value="0" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: price">
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text: itemCost">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfooter>
    <tr>
      <td>Total cost</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td data-bind="text: totalCost"></td>

    </tr>
  </tfooter>
</table>
```